# Will it be a crime if I post data into someone's website using cURL?

Tags: curl, crime

I found a website which is not secure and tried to post a form on that site using cURL request in PHP and it worked successfully.

However, that is a simple site with contact form and no special or secure data. Anyone can fill that form. I just did that with curl with a loop of 100.

Is this a crime?

Comment: That's going to depend on the law where you are located, and the law where the website is hosted

Comment: // , @VinitSingh, this is an example of a good subjective question! Would you mind expanding a little on a definition of the word "crime" as used here?

Comment: // , And of course, it might be courteous to send a gentle security comment, assuming that there's a way to do so anonymously.

Comment: Voting to close because this is a legal question, not a security question. As for whether doing this could be considered *malicious* - absolutely, yes.

Comment: @NathanBasanese By "crime" i mean will it land me into some legal issue. Can owner of site file a complaint against me even though there was issue in there own site.

Comment: Also voting to close because it's a legal and not security question.  As for whether it's considered malicious... only if you're doing something malicious with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most browsers have developer tools which allow you to monitor all HTTP(S) requests sent by the browser, including an option to copy the requests as a cURL command. If you execute the request via cURL, it's *indistinguishable* from a 'real' browser request. Therefore, that is certainly not a crime.

If you're looping cURL requests, you're essentially trying to perform a [Denial of Service attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Legality); many countries/states have laws which state that this is a crime. Though 100 requests are not likely to constitute a *successful* attack, all it might do is fill the inbox of the mail account which receives completed forms.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a lawyer, and the world is a large place with many conflicting laws, so I can't say anything about the legality of using cURL...

But from a technical standpoint, anything that you can do to their server with cURL, you can also do with a web browser.  Anything that you can do to their server with a web browser, you can also do with cURL.  They are simply programs that follow the HTTP protocol.

Of course, you can commit crimes with browsers, so it's *possible* to use cURL to commit crimes as well, but just the fact that you used cURL does not turn non-criminal browsing into a criminal act, unless the countries involved have some very specific laws.

To your specific point, if there is any crime in submitting data to a form on an insecure website 100 times in a row, then it shouldn't matter if you used cURL or if you just copy/pasted the information into the form and hit the submit button in the browser 100 times.